# How to fix Row 0 given with size different than 0 error in Google charts?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, charts, google-visualization

I am working with google charts for the first time and I have no idea about the errors of this library. Please guide me where I am wrong.

[image]

```
    let initFlag = (this.leaderBoardData == null) ? true : false;
    let chartData = leaderBoardData;
    if (!this.resize) {
      for (var data of chartData) {
        let strLen = 14;
        let uname = data.username;
        let title = (uname.length > strLen) ? uname.substring(0, strLen) + '...' : uname;
        let value = data.socialPoint;
        let color = data.colorCode;
        let tooltipValue = data.userName + '\n Count: ' + value;
        this.usageData.push([title, value, color, value, tooltipValue]);
      }
    }

    let gcData = new google.visualization.DataTable();

    if (initFlag) {
      gcData.addColumn('string', 'Dealer Name');
      gcData.addColumn('number', 'Count');
      gcData.addColumn({ type: 'string', role: "style" });
      gcData.addColumn({ type: 'number', role: "annotation" });
      gcData.addColumn({ type: 'string', role: 'tooltip' });
    }

    gcData.addRows(this.usageData);
```

**Response from console**

[image]

Any solution appreciated!

Comment: this error is thrown when the array provided to the `addRows` method has a different number of elements than the number of columns in the existing data table. given that it specifies zero as the number of columns, I can only assume that the `initFlag` variable is `false` and the columns were not added to the data table, prior to adding the rows.